# Error when opening shell scripts

Tags: bash

I began to get the error

```
Error detected while processing BufRead Auto commands for "*.sh":
E117: Unknown function: dist#ft#SetFileTypeSH
```

when I opened shell scripts (*.sh)
I think it happened after updating from a 7.x version to 8.0.

How can it be fixed?

As suggested, I did a search for the function in `/usr/share/vim/vim80/autoload/dist/ft.vim`

```
" Called from filetype.vim and scripts.vim.
func dist#ft#SetFileTypeSH(name)
  if expand("<amatch>") =~ g:ft_ignore_pat
    return
  endif
  if a:name =~ '\<csh\>'
    " Some .sh scripts contain #!/bin/csh.
    call dist#ft#SetFileTypeShell("csh")
    return
  elseif a:name =~ '\<tcsh\>'
    " Some .sh scripts contain #!/bin/tcsh.
    call dist#ft#SetFileTypeShell("tcsh")
    return
  elseif a:name =~ '\<zsh\>'
    " Some .sh scripts contain #!/bin/zsh.
    call dist#ft#SetFileTypeShell("zsh")
    return
  elseif a:name =~ '\<ksh\>'
    let b:is_kornshell = 1
    if exists("b:is_bash")
      unlet b:is_bash
    endif
    if exists("b:is_sh")
      unlet b:is_sh
    endif
  elseif exists("g:bash_is_sh") || a:name =~ '\<bash\>' || a:name =~ '\<bash2\>'
    let b:is_bash = 1
    if exists("b:is_kornshell")
      unlet b:is_kornshell
    endif
    if exists("b:is_sh")
      unlet b:is_sh
    endif
  elseif a:name =~ '\<sh\>'
    let b:is_sh = 1
    if exists("b:is_kornshell")
      unlet b:is_kornshell
    endif
    if exists("b:is_bash")
      unlet b:is_bash
    endif
  endif
  call dist#ft#SetFileTypeShell("sh")
endfunc
```

Is anything wrong with it?

I also noticed that syntax highlighting stopped working too.

I noticed that if I don't use the session file vim can open shell scripts without errors.

I think the session file is the culprit. There must be some backwards compatibility problems between versions 8 and 7 as the session file worked fine in VIM 7. But how to locate the error... I don't want to create the session file from scratch.

Comment: Launch vim. `:e $VIM/vim80/autoload/dist/ft.vim` and search for `SH`—you should find the function. If it’s not there or you are missing the file, you may need to reinstall vim or its runtime files. It may be `vim81` if you are using 8.1.

Comment: did you install correctly? Sounds like your vim (more exactly the runtime files) was not properly installed

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Not sure. I only remember that before upgrading Kubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04 there was a 7.x version of vim installed, but after the upgrade it became 8.0.

Comment: Try checking with `:echo $VIMRUNTIME`

Comment: @tivn There is no such variable

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt How to do it properly? I have just run: "sudo apt-get --reinstall install vim" but the error remained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to recreate the session file. As I didn't want to create it from scratch I copied the crucial parts from it - open files/buffers.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your `.vimrc` file is not upgraded when you upgrade your vim version. It still contain old runtime path. The easiest way to fix it will be to update `runtimepath` in `.vimrc`

For example, In vim 8.0 the runtimetimepath should be like

```
set runtimepath=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim80,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after
```

But if you just upgraded from Vim 7.4 to Vim 8.0 the line will look like:

```
set runtimepath=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after
```

In that case changing the `vim74` to `vim80` will solve the problem

Comment: First, I solved the issue by recreating the session file and posted the answer before you. Shouldn't it indicate that runtime has nothing to do with the problem? Second, I checked the runtime in my .vimrc. It's - runtime macros/matchit.vim. How should it be obvious that it's "old"? What is "new" version? You haven't written it.

Comment: @ka3ak edited my answer :)

Comment: @ka3ak (a bit late though) well in Sessions file you must update your `runtimepath` with the corresponding output of `:echo $VIMRUNTIME`