# How to debug "Unknown function: dist#ft#SetFileTypeSH" after upgrade to 8.1

Tags: filetype

edit: Solution found! At the bottom of the post

---

I installed vim 8.1 via brew on macos Sierra yesterday, and I think that broke some of the filetype setting stuff.  When I open a shell script, I get the following error:

```
Error detected while processing /usr/local/share/vim/vim81/scripts.vim:
line   69:
E117: Unknown function: dist#ft#SetFileTypeSH
```

The closest answer I could find was [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17136/error-when-opening-shell-scripts), but I'm not using a session (and the error message is a little different)

I also see a different error if I put my cursor over a parenthesis in a vim script. I don't know if it's related:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>50_Highlight_Matching_Pair:
line   97:
E475: Invalid argument: 0
```

I tried disabling all my plugins (Just commented out the Vundle lines in my .vimrc and launched vim in a new shell), but it didn't seem to help.

`runtimepath` looks ok, referencing `/usr/local/share/vim/vim81`.

I'm not sure what to do next.  It seems like that function (SetFileTypeSH) is missing from Vim 8.1.

A bit of extra background: I *think* I was using vim 8.1 last week without issue, but a macos update broke my brew links, so I had to reinstall it and tinker with some symlinks to make it work again.  So the problem is probably related to that in some way, I just don't know what to do next to debug it.

---

Solution:

The problem was that the autoload directory ($VIM_INSTALL_PATH/vim81/autoload) was empty, so a bunch of scripts were missing.

Somehow the autoload directory was owned by root , and was not writable by group users.  I solved it by uninstalling vim via brew (`brew uninstall vim`), then deleting the vim81 directory manually (`sudo rm -rf $VIM_INSTALL_PATH/vim81`), then reinstalled with brew. (`brew install vim`), followed by re-linking (`brew link vim`) to get it all working.

Seemed to fix the Highlight_Matching_Pair issue too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `'runtimepath'` is correct, then you seem to be missing the `/usr/local/share/vim/vim81/autoload/dist/ft.vim` file; it ships with Vim 8.1. Check the file system and reinstall if necessary.

---

That error in `<SNR>50_Highlight_Matching_Pair` seems to be in the *matchparen++* plugin. I had submitted a patch for that problem to the author; you can download the fixed version 1.0.3 from [vim.org](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2059).

Comment: Ah-ha! You got it! the whole autoload directory is empty!  I wonder why brew would leave that out.

<hr/>

Huh, I didn't think I had that plugin, since I don't recognize the name.  Could it be bundled with another plugin?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: edit: Figured out the former.  Somehow the autoload directory was owned by root , and was not writable by group users.  I just uninstalled vim via brew, then sudo rm -rf'd the vim81 directory, then did `brew install vim` again, followed by `brew link vim` to get it all working.

Seemed to fix the Highlight_Matching_Pair issue too!

(adding this to main post too, for posterity)

Comment: Ah, then it was the matchparen plugin (note: no ++) that ships with Vim.

Comment: This isn't working for me, but I need to use macvim instead of vim. I checked my runtime autoload and it's got stuff in it and nothing is owned by root. But I'm getting that error. It started after I ran `brew upgrade`. I even just tried :PlugClean, :PlugInstall, :PlugUpdate, which all worked.

Comment: Huh. I just figured out, I only have the problem when I open gvim with -S Session.vim. I guess I have to remake my million-tab-and-window session